# Gcloud app deploy failing with error response [5] - cannot get cloud region in global job

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I'm hosting my angular website with app engine, and have build triggers set up to automatically deploy my website when I push to master on my github repo.

Up until last night, this all worked fine. I've changed nothing in either my app.yaml or my cloudbuild.yaml files, but now my builds are failing on the "gcloud app deploy" step with the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [5] Cannot get cloud region in global job.
```

I even reran some old builds that had previously passed and they now fail. Can't really find anything online for this so I'm a bit lost as to what to do really. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: This issue seems to have been resolved now. I reran some of the failing builds again without changing anything and they worked. I can only assume it was an internal GCP issue.